# PHP - Encode base64 with UTF-16 Schema

Tags: php, base64, utf-16

I'm trying to encode strings in base64 with UTF-16 schema.

For testing, I'm using this online tool, that works perfect, but I need it in php code:

https://8gwifi.org/Base64Functions.jsp

Setting config on:
[Encode - Schema UTF-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10z89.png)

At this moment I tryed this:

```
$str = '/v8AVABoAGkAcwAgAGkAcwAgAGEAbgAgAGUAbgBjAG8AZABlAGQAIABzAHQAcgBpAG4AZw==';
$str = base64_decode($str);
$str = iconv("UTF-16", "ISO-8859-1", $str);
echo $str.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

//$str = 'This is an encoded string';
$str = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-16", $str);
$str = base64_encode($str);

echo $str;
```

First conversion works well. Takes encoded string, decodes correctly, everything ok.

But reverse conversion outputs this:

```
//5UAGgAaQBzACAAaQBzACAAYQBuACAAZQBuAGMAbwBkAGUAZAAgAHMAdAByAGkAbgBnAA==
```

Witch is not the same.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't you lose information when going from UTF-16 to ISO-8859-1? If so, the reverse operation would never work.

Comment: No, from UTF-16 to ISO-8859-1 the string is showing correctly:
First echo outputs
"This is an encoded string"
Second one outputs
"//5UAGgAaQBzACAAaQBzACAAYQBuACAAZQBuAGMAbwBkAGUAZAAgAHMAdAByAGkAbgBnAA=="

Comment: for test, you can copy-paste my code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ or any other php test online tool

Comment: Well if your string is only `"This is an encoded string"`... going from UTF-16 to ISO is not going to change/lose anything. Try something more robust like a string `"This is some Kanji 漢字"` . iso will mangle that.

Comment: Looks like, for some reason (couldn't find an answer why iconv does this), iconv is adding a BOM to your string when it converts to utf-16. The difference on your tests is the hex code of `fffe` in front. Which is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: The original string, just after base64 decoding, also has a BOM. The byte orders of the pre-`iconv` string and the post-`iconv` string are different.

Comment: There is a link with all of my tests: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4c04af111359fb58bfa323d0bb4690cbd8f5515. Just saw the BOM just after `base64_decode` is quite different than after `$str = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-16", $str)`

Answer (score -1):

/$str = 'This is an encoded string';

encryption and decryption is working fine without any external support in php version

7.2.5

Please try

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is saying nothing. As you can see on my post, I tryed with it, and it doesn't work.